# Can we integrate kibana with kendo-ui?

Tags: elasticsearch, kendo-ui, kibana-4

I tried to integrated kibana with kendo-ui to view the visuals at the kibana dashboard.Is that possible to do like that?

Answer (score 0):

yes.. but there is no official process provided by kibana @team.. I have done this using creating custom visualization plugin..

Plugin index.js

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function (kibana) {

  return new kibana.Plugin({

    uiExports: {
      visTypes: ['plugins/kendo_vislib_vis_types/kendo_vislib_vis_types']
    }

  });
};
```

kendo_vislib_vis_types

```
define(function (require) {
  const visTypes = require('ui/registry/vis_types');
  visTypes.register(require('plugins/kendo_vislib_vis_types/line'));
  visTypes.register(require('plugins/kendo_vislib_vis_types/bar'));
  visTypes.register(require('plugins/kendo_vislib_vis_types/pie'));
  visTypes.register(require('plugins/kendo_vislib_vis_types/metric'));
});
```

Remaining followed http://logz.io/blog/kibana-visualizations/

esResponse Data should be formatted in kendo required format using

```
$scope.$watch('esResponse', function (resp) {
     if (resp) {
       var currentState = $scope.vis.getState();
       $scope.vis.setState(ktInterval.changeInterval(currentState));

       $scope.kendoOptionGroup = [];
      //  console.log(tabifyAggResponse($scope.vis, resp));
      $scope.resp = +moment();
      $scope.processTableGroups(tabifyAggResponse($scope.vis, resp));

     }
   });
```

Note: CSS files injected with hardcoded way directly into src/ui/ui_app.jade,  because though plugin means css images path should be in kibana understandable format which need modify manually in kendo.*.min.css.

kendo CSS files injecting to kibana

```
var files = [
        bundleFile('commons.style.css'),
        bundleFile('kendo/styles/kendo.default.min.css'),
        bundleFile('kendo/styles/kendo.common.min.css'),
        bundleFile('#{app.id}.style.css'),
        bundleFile('custom.style.css'),
        bundleFile('commons.bundle.js'),
        bundleFile('#{app.id}.bundle.js')
      ];
```